# How can I create a mysql db with Docker compose?

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I'm trying to host on docker an application which uses MySQL db. I'm using docker compose. my yml file looks like this:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
  data_sql:    
services:  
medical-mysql:
    image: mysql
    hostname: medical-mysql    
    volumes:    
     - data_sql:/dbcreation.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Medical
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      STARTUP_SQL: data_sql
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  medical-main:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"    
    depends_on:
     - medical-mysql
```

I have a `dbcreation.sql` which creates the db schema and is kept in the yml folder. When I run the yml file it seems as if the file is not running.

What have I missed?

Comment: So what  is data_sql and when you call dbcreation.sql ?

Comment: data_sql is simply the volume I created to host the creation file. I couldn't find any other way to do it, and this one also doesn't work.

Comment: It seems you are mounting data_sql in dbcreation.sql. You never create the db. You need to copy in /var/lib/mysql (and not dbcreation.sql if you want to use it you need to execute something like that : mysql -u user db < dbcreation.sql )

Answer (score 31):

Simply just put your .sql file (dbcreation.sql) in a folder (ie. /mysql_init) and add the folder as a volume like this:

```
volumes:
  - /mysql_init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

The MySQL image will execute all .sql, .sh and .sql.gz files in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d on startup.

Comment: where this folder should be? At project level or a docker container?

Answer (score 25):

1) Create dump file **dbcreation.sql**

2) Create **import.sh** file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mysql -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD < /tmp/dbcreation.sql
```

3) Create **docker-compose.yaml**

```
database:
  image: mysql
  container_name: database.dev
  command: mysqld --user=root --verbose
  volumes:
    - ./dbcreation.sql:/tmp/dbcreation.sql
    - ./import.sh:/tmp/import.sh
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: "test"
    MYSQL_USER: "test"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: "test"
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
```

*"- ./dbcreation.sql:/tmp/dbcreation.sql" - "- local_path:path_inside_container"*

4) Run

```
docker-compose up
docker exec database.dev bash /tmp/import.sh
```

Comment: I had a problem implementing your answer since once my main container is up, it needs the db constructed. It did give me many clues of getting where I wanted. I split the mysql container creation into a seperate yml file. I made an sh file with the following:

docker-compose -f mysql.yml up -d
sleep 10;
docker exec medical-mysql bash /tmp/import.sh
docker-compose up

It works. Is there a better way to make sure the mysql container is ready than the sleep?

Comment: @IzharLotem it is not about container, it is about application inside. Container is ready, but application inside the container doesn't.
You need to resolve it on application level. You can check health of MySQL database in your "main container" or you can overwrite CMD inside Dockerfile and put flag somewhere after import will be done. Anyway it is not docker job.

Comment: Running against 8.0.11, I needed to change "command" to:
command: mysqld --user=root --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
This allowed me to connect via MySQL Workbench (v6.3)

Comment: I get: /tmp/import.sh: /tmp/import.sh: Is a directory