# Is there any way to create schema and tables in mysql docker without build a new image for mysql?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, sql-scripts

I have 2 images. One of them is custom and the other one is `mysql`. I am using `docker-compose`. Its database part is given below.

```
   db:
      image: mysql
      container_name: mysql-docker-test
      volumes:
         - test-sql:/var/lib/mysql
      restart: always
      networks:
         test-net:
            ipv4_address: 172.17.0.5
      ports:
         - "3306:3306"
      environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_secret_pw
```

There is no problem with communication but I need to run sql script when I run `docker-compose up`.

Is there any way to run sql script in `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a mysql db with Docker compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845144/how-can-i-create-a-mysql-db-with-docker-compose)

Answer (score 0):

you can override the `entrypoint` or the `command` in `docker-compose.yml` like this :

```
db:
  image: mysql
  entrypoint: ./path_to_your_script.sh
```

In your script you must start mysql server and then run your sql scripts. Of course you msut put the shell script in a volume.